# Removing the white space & prettier css

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I've made my own static website from scratch using html5 and css(3) only.But I have got 2 issues.

The **first one** is the white space between the top's menu and header's image bottom.I've tried everything.

Maybe the only solution for that is `float:left;` but then the image goes into the navigation tag or negative value on margin's property but I've heard that this technique is bad.

The **second issue** I'll display via image http://www.filedropper.com/discoversite that's my simple WebSite. I know my css is awful but I'm still a beginner. The second issue is here. http://postimg.org/image/5adp6379d/ . As you can see the text is going out of the box. (I am using `%` in css for more responsive). I will be glad if anyone can help me.

Comment: you should post some code of what you have tried, or a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/);

Comment: One tip for your "text out of the box" issue is to set a min-width. % are a great way to go when it comes to sizing your containers, but there comes a point when a certain % becomes useless. Set your min-width and then decide how to handle overflow as well. You can use overflow:scroll or overflow:hidden for nice results.

Comment: Thank you very much. min-width is the right thing I've been searching for.God bless you and thank you. Now the only problem I have is that white space.Still searching how to fix it.But anyways.Thank you for your answer , helpful buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I can only have a guess for your first issue as I don't know the exact code for your website (create jsfiddle :D ). Try to apply `vertical-align: bottom;` or `display: block;` to your header image. Why? Because images are placed like text and some letters like <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> are going underneath the bottom level. Your browser will leave a tiny space for these letters. Also setting a `min-width` is a good solution like Kirk Logan said.
2. And for your second problem there are multiple solutions (depending on what you want):

   - You can handle your content with `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: scroll` as Kirk Logan suggested. But this wouldn't make any sense in the case you have shown us in the picture.
   - Or (is a little more complex) you could remove the white borders on the left and right side (just when the screen is too small) in order to gain more space for the text. This can be done by:

     ```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
         #BigBorder1 { border-width: 0px; }
         #BigBorder2 { border-width: 0px; }
     }
     ```

*Everthing inside the outer brackets will only be applied when the screen's width is smaller than 768px. But to be honest this is usually done the other way round: When the screen is bigger than 768px then something happens. This simplification is only in order to make it easier for you.*

Comment: If this helped you, could you please mark this question as answered? This is the gray little ☑ at the left side of an answer. This would help me, you and all the others who have the same issue as you :-)

Comment: And is the white space still there? What happens when you apply vertical-align: bottom; to your header image? Will the white space go away? Or could you try setting your image as display: block;?

Comment: Yes , it fits perfectly now! By the way , let me ask you something more If I may. Do I have always to build my menu in ul and list items? Can't I just place my a href links in nav tag and that's it. I am asking you that because I am very bad in menu styling :d

Comment: Okay so thank you for your help once again. I think I made your answer as "checked".Sorry but I am totally new in this society.Good luck bro! Regards.